# Can I copy Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 workflow descriptions between assemblies?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We've got a bunch of CRM2011 workflow assemblies that I'm performing modifications upon. Unlike in CRM4, the text that describes the workflow and the group it appears in in the CRM workflow designer are set in the plug-in registration tool, rather than in the code.

As some of the libraries have 50+ workflow activities, this gives me the monotonous task of retyping all of the groups and titles for the activities every time I release the library again (something that's happening several times per day and taking up far too much time).

Is there a way of copying the descriptions from the old version of the workflow assembly to the new that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially export the configuration xml from the plug in registration tool for the CRM 4 version and then copy the relevant sections to your configuration xml for 2011 and re-register the assemblies with the xml to get the updated descriptions? Still a bit manual, bit certainly faster than doing it all via the UI for each process?

If you are using the developer tool kit in CRM 2011 then the CrmPackage prject maintains a version of this xml and you can update it and deploy direct from VS.